# yourls.org error creating table

Tags: runtime-error, yourls

I'm trying to install yourls.org url shortener software on my server in a subdirectory: http://[mydomain.tld]/y/admin/install.php. Numerous install attempts result in the following errors:

```
Error creating table 'y20130519_url'.
Error creating table 'y20130519_options'.
Error creating table 'y20130519_log'.
Error creating YOURLS tables.

File .htaccess successfully created/updated.
```

I've double-checked the db user and password. I even tried creating new ones. I've reinstalled a few times.

In phpMyAdmin, I verify that no tables have been added to the database, as suggested by the errors.

In the config file, I modified the following [sensitive info replaced generically here]:

```
define( 'YOURLS_DB_USER', '[my new db user name is here]' );

define( 'YOURLS_DB_PASS', '[my new db password is here]' );

define( 'YOURLS_DB_NAME', '[my new db name is here]' );

define( 'YOURLS_DB_PREFIX', 'y20130519_' );

define( 'YOURLS_SITE', 'http://[mydomain.tld]/y' );

define( 'YOURLS_HOURS_OFFSET', -5 ); 

define( 'YOURLS_COOKIEKEY', '[I typed random characters here]' );

$yourls_user_passwords = array(
'[I created new user]' => '[I created new password]',
'[I created another new user]' => '[I created another new password]'    // You can have one or more 'login'=>'password' lines
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Double check if you "user" is added to your database in "MySQL Databases" and have rights to change/edit/modify/add.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed yourls today same error

```
Error creating table 'yourls_url'.
Error creating table 'yourls_options'.
Error creating table 'yourls_log'.
Error creating YOURLS tables.

File .htaccess successfully created/updated.
```

But .. is not true i've checked the db and all the tables are working

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the YOURLS code that has been solved:

https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/issues/1617

Wait for the new version, or change the code as above url yourself.